# my component language does not read in joomla after I changed some thing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I tried to install same component for two and three times but this cant be possible , so i gonna change the name of the back end for install more time .
i did like this :

download a text changer and changed all the (`Org name`)Text with the (N`ew name`)text & all folders with same name too .

```
((Org name = Spsimpleportfolio))
((New Name = Spsimpleamir))
```

---

after this i installed the component successfully and work well but i have a problem :

i think my en-Gb language in joomla do not read because here i see the coding texts . 
Example:
`.ini File >>  COM_SPSIMPLEPORTFOLIO="SP Simple amir"` and i see the `"COM_SPSIMPLEPORTFOLIO"` in my site not the "`SP Simple amir`".

[image: Here is an image of admin's component i see]

Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND language in ('en-GB','*')' at line 3 SQL=SELECT `spsimpleamir_tag_id`,`title`,`alias` FROM `sd0o9_spsimpleamir_tags` WHERE `spsimpleamir_tag_id` IN () AND language in ('en-GB','*')

Answer (score 1):

Because you've changed the name of the component, system can't find it's language files anymore. However this is an easy thing to fix, go to `/administrator/language/en-GB` and `/language/en-GB` there look for a file `en-GB.com_OLD_component_name.ini` (if exists also the same `en-GB.com_OLD_component_name.sys.ini`), copy them in the same folder but with different names `en-GB.com_NEW_component_name.ini` and `.sys.ini` version too.

After this, if you've changed the names correctly, the component will find it's language files and use them.

Comment: i did it before but still not read the en-GB.look the picture link... [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/wbdnux.jpg)